# speech recognition don't recognise my micro

Tags: python

I'm doing a personal assistant with Python, using the 'speech recognition' library, but when i run the app, it doesn't recognise my micro. It doesn't show any error in the console.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.runAndWait()

try:
    with sr.microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...') 
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        command = command.lower()

except:
    print('Error, try again')
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Which operating system?  Does the microphone work in apps like Audacity?

Comment: On Windows 11, the funny thing is that in audacity it works.

Comment: Do you see the "Listening..." line?  That would suggest that the microphone IS being recognized, it's just not recognizing anything you are saying.